# IE scrape on Win 10 - Object failing to have document subtag when internetexplorermedium

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

Sorry about the confusing title I couldn't think of something better.

I'm trying to do a scrape of an intranet site and have my code working on my local machine. The problem is that some coworkers pcs have IE set to use a new instance when going to untrusted sites.

I was able to solve the errors that occurred with the following code.

```
'Cannot create object due to Settings in IE
'Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
Set oIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
oIE.Visible = True
```

So now my coworkers PC follows the IE object around perfectly.

However when we get to the following line it fails, and upon looking at the new object, it doesn't have a .Document sub While the initially created object would.

```
Set tdElementCollection = oIE.document.getelementsbytagname("tr")
```

Hoping for any assistance.

To be clear - my guess here is that the object type internetexplorermedium simply doesn' thave a .document sub for some reason.

--Edit - Additionally requested code

```
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until oIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Do
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
Loop Until InStr(oIE.document.getelementsbytagname("title")(0).innerText, "XXXXXXXX")

While oIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
```

Comment: where is the code that waits for the DocumentComplete event?

Comment: Posted Edited with it there :)

Comment: your web site is probably running at low instead of medium integrity level. see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/

Comment: So by design InternetExplorerMedium doesn't have a .document subheading?

Comment: it does have a document property. The document property can be null at times.

Comment: How would I get the document property to not be null?

To be clear - It isn't null on my PC (Windows 7)

But is clear on my coworkers PC (Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Had to DIM in a new variable, and set it as the .document property then change my tdelementcollection variable to use that instead of oie.document

```
Dim HTMLDoc as HTMLDOCUMENT

set htmldoc = oie.document

Set tdElementCollection = htmldoc.getelementsbytagname("tr")
```